# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\test.bata.com'. when launching ASP.NET Core application from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I am deploying my ASP.NET application on IIS. Everything works well when I run it on Visual Studio with IIS Express but when I use IIS, the event viewer shows this error.

[image: Event Viewer Error]

I added a login on SQL Server but still get the same error

[image: SQL Server Login]

Any idea on what I could be missing?

Comment: Can you show me your connection string? because you are using Windows authentification, you need to set Integrated Security in the connection string to true, or you can try to replace the username and password with Integrated Security=SSPI.

Comment: `Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Bata_Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

Answer (score 0):

Grand DB_Owner permission for "IIS APPPOOL\test.bata.com". also check the connection string in web.config file

Comment: what type connection credentials (Windows / SQL) you are passing in the DBContext.

Comment: Windows authentification

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use custom identity in application pool with the windows user name password and use this string in web.config file.

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="data source=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;database=nrc;Integrated Security=SSPI;persist security info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For more detailed steps you can refer to this link: https://forums.iis.net/t/1249665.aspx